# react-native-config: cannot find symbol

Tags: java, react-native, cannot-find-symbol, react-native-config

I've got a fresh React Native app, where I'm trying to use `react-native-config`:

```
npx react-native init RNConfigDemo
cd RNConfigDemo

yarn add react-native-config
echo "SOME_VAR="something"" > .env
```

I tried to add a line in my `./android/app/src/main/java/com/rnconfigdemo/MainActivity.java`:

```
...
  return BuildConfig.SOME_VAR;
...
```

and I always get the following:

```
RNConfigDemo/android/app/src/main/java/com/rnconfigdemo/MainActivity.java:40: error: cannot find symbol
    return BuildConfig.SOME_VAR;
                                                               ^
  symbol:   variable SOME_VAR
  location: class BuildConfig
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
1 error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception
```

I can access non-`.env` defined `BuildConfig`, such as `BuildConfig.DEBUG`, with no issues. But my defined `BuildConfig` properties throw the above

I've tried running `npx react-native link react-native-config`, despite this having been autolinked, as well as the troubleshooting guidelines.

I verified the manually linked additions were present in their respective files.

I tried adding `import com.facebook.react.BuildConfig`, and then `import com.rnconfigdemo.BuildConfig`, to no avail.

I've followed all the steps for the Android build in the package's `README`

What's the issue here?

Comment: what about this step - https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config#extra-step-for-android

Comment: @imKrishh Thanks, I thought that was part of the troubleshooting to check that. Added that and refreshed the build and cache, to no avail